# How to run shell command within my app

Tags: macos, shell

I am making a OS X app that needs to run an OS X shell command. I have a `.command` file containing the shell commands I needs to execute. Now how do I execute it. I know how to execute a single command, but how do you execute all the commands within the shell `.command` file.

My machine is OS X 10.11 Xcode 7.2.1

**UPDATE**:
Here are my codes:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSTask *task;
    NSPipe *pipe;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self runCommand:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"command"] arguments:nil];
}

- (void)runCommand:(NSString *)cmd arguments:(NSArray *)args {
    if (task)
    {
        [task interrupt];

    }
    else
    {
        task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath:cmd];

        [task setArguments:args];

        pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
        [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

        NSFileHandle* fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

        [task launch];
        [fh readInBackgroundAndNotify];
    }
}

@end
```

**UPDATE 2**:
Here are the error code: `Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): must provide array of arguments`

Comment: If you can execute a single command, just execute the `.command` file. It can also be an executable.

Comment: @Arc676 So you can do: `[task setLaunchPath:theContentOfTheCommandFile];`

Comment: You can try the path to the command file as launch path.

Comment: @Arc676 I got this error when running, the update are my codes.

Comment: Here are the error: `Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): must provide array of arguments`

Comment: You should include error messages and code in your post, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a bit of playing around with the parameter, you can't put nil into the args parameter. The updated viewDidLoad would be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self runCommand:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"command"] arguments:@[]];
}
```